# {REQUEST_URI} in .htaccess not matching properly for SSL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

Hey, I'm trying to use .htaccess to force SSL on a page on my website.

In my .htaccess I'm doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} auth/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shop.mysite.co.uk/auth/login [R=301,L]
```

So I'm going to this page: http://shop.mysite.co.uk/auth/login - hoping it's forced to be https by .htaccess

I know it works as I'm sure I had it working earlier. But I have a horrible feeling I changed something and don't know what and now it won't work! When I go to http://shop.mysite.co.uk/auth/login it just loads the page using http as normal and not https.

It seems to be this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` auth/login that is not working properly, if I remove that line it redirects any url to https://shop.mysite.co.uk/auth/login.

Comment: Do you use some other rules besides this one?

Comment: Yeah but this box wont let me enter it all!

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RedirectMatch 403 ^/(application\/cache|codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /auth/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shop.mysite.co.uk/auth/login [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: you can edit it into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using other rules besides the mentioned one, make sure to put those rules, that cause an external redirect (i.e. *R* flag), in front of those rules, that only cause an internal rewrite. Otherwise an already internally rewritten rule can already have changed your request URL and your pattern will not match.

Comment: As you can sort of see from the poorly formatted code above, my problem rule is the last thing in there.

Comment: @audiopleb: … and the first rule is probably applied and the URL is already rewritten before the last one is tested.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! It was simply the ordering of the rules that was messing that up.

Thanks for all the help you gave, i'm very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` will have a prefixing slash. This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /auth/login
```

Comment: Just tried that, no dice! I'm at a total loss as to why this is not working :(